# Does Mac OS call display methods such as drawRect: concurrently from different threads? Isn't that dangerous when accessing the data model?

Tags: multithreading, macos, cocoa, nsview

We have a subclass of NSTableRowView that overwrites drawSelectionInRect: (which is internally called by drawRect:). This method needs to access the NSManagedObjectContext, so as a sanity check we have an assertion there that we are in the main thread. Now it turns out that sometimes Apple calls drawRect from a non-main-thread (example stack trace below). Does this mean it could even do that concurrently from two different threads? I.e. we have to take care of thread safety ourselves when overwriting drawRect: and using the data model?

```
ERROR: Assertion failed: [NSThread isMainThread]:  (ZS_AppDelegate.m:1287)
(
    0   tomedo_kunden                       0x00000001008af46a -[ZS_AppDelegate loggedInUser] + 554
    1   tomedo_kunden                       0x00000001016feca7 +[Nutzer loggedInUser] + 71
    2   tomedo_kunden                       0x0000000100f33397 +[ZSUserDefaults(MacOS) colorFromPreferences:] + 167
    3   tomedo_kunden                       0x00000001003d8265 -[Besuch(BesuchCategory) baseTextColor] + 101
    4   tomedo_kunden                       0x000000010071f846 -[ZSTableRowView drawSelectionInRect:] + 806
    5   AppKit                              0x00007fffd189d26c -[NSTableRowView drawRect:] + 242
    6   AppKit                              0x00007fffd184eba3 -[NSView(NSInternal) _recursive:displayRectIgnoringOpacity:inGraphicsContext:CGContext:topView:shouldChangeFontReferenceColor:] + 1318
    7   AppKit                              0x00007fffd184f053 -[NSView(NSInternal) _recursive:displayRectIgnoringOpacity:inGraphicsContext:CGContext:topView:shouldChangeFontReferenceColor:] + 2518
    8   AppKit                              0x00007fffd184e548 __46-[NSView(NSLayerKitGlue) drawLayer:inContext:]_block_invoke + 267
    9   AppKit                              0x00007fffd184e071 -[NSView(NSLayerKitGlue) _drawViewBackingLayer:inContext:drawingHandler:] + 1589
    10  AppKit                              0x00007fffd184da36 -[NSView(NSLayerKitGlue) drawLayer:inContext:] + 80
    11  AppKit                              0x00007fffd19839ff -[_NSBackingLayerContents drawLayer:inContext:] + 162
    12  QuartzCore                          0x00007fffd96a1e42 -[CALayer drawInContext:] + 257
    13  AppKit                              0x00007fffd19834d8 -[_NSTiledLayer drawTile:inContext:] + 624
    14  AppKit                              0x00007fffd198320e -[_NSTiledLayerContents drawLayer:inContext:] + 176
    15  QuartzCore                          0x00007fffd96a1e42 -[CALayer drawInContext:] + 257
    16  AppKit                              0x00007fffd1983155 -[NSTileLayer drawInContext:] + 169
    17  QuartzCore                          0x00007fffd9584a38 CABackingStoreUpdate_ + 3740
    18  QuartzCore                          0x00007fffd96a1a3c ___ZN2CA5Layer8display_Ev_block_invoke + 75
    19  QuartzCore                          0x00007fffd96a169d _ZN2CA5Layer8display_Ev + 1803
    20  AppKit                              0x00007fffd198306c -[NSTileLayer display] + 119
    21  QuartzCore                          0x00007fffd9695546 _ZN2CA5Layer17display_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 572
    22  QuartzCore                          0x00007fffd9695671 _ZN2CA5Layer28layout_and_display_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 35
    23  QuartzCore                          0x00007fffd968ae88 _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 280
    24  QuartzCore                          0x00007fffd9581d55 _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 475
    25  AppKit                              0x00007fffd19701d9 __58-[_NSScrollingConcurrentVBLMonitor _updateScrollAnimation]_block_invoke + 972
    26  AppKit                              0x00007fffd196aa3a -[_NSScrollingConcurrentSharedData threadSafePropertyAccess:] + 44
    27  AppKit                              0x00007fffd196d127 -[_NSScrollingConcurrentVBLMonitor _updateScrollAnimation] + 672
    28  AppKit                              0x00007fffd196c84e -[_NSScrollingConcurrentVBLMonitor _synchronizeForVBLSerialNumber:timestamp:updateDuration:] + 561
    29  AppKit                              0x00007fffd196c5ad __42-[_NSScrollingConcurrentVBLMonitor resume]_block_invoke + 218
    30  AppKit                              0x00007fffd196c4ca __45-[NSScreen(NSScreenUpdate) addUpdateHandler:]_block_invoke_2 + 212
    31  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010345ffcc _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    32  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000103476bca _dispatch_continuation_pop + 1025
    33  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010346c6bc _dispatch_source_latch_and_call + 195
    34  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000103462e15 _dispatch_source_invoke + 1106
    35  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001034768f0 _dispatch_continuation_pop + 295
    36  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010346deda _dispatch_async_redirect_invoke + 777
    37  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000103462247 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 671
    38  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000103461f58 _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 114
    39  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00000001034d78c2 _pthread_wqthread + 1299
    40  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00000001034d739d start_wqthread + 13
)
```

Comment: If you're accessing CoreData directly from the drawRect, you should revise your architecture.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

NSView subclasses can draw concurrently in recent releases of OS X.  This behavior can be turned off by overriding `canDrawConcurrently` and returning `NO`.

You might find it preferable to separate the view from the model a little more and isolate the data to be rendered from the CoreData managed data a bit;  pull the data to be rendered out into a local-only representation and let AppKit concurrently update the view.

https://developer.apple.com/reference/appkit/nsview/1483425-candrawconcurrently